# jquery not work with local reference but work with google reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery in my web project.

When I use local reference like this;

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I receive this error:

> $ is not a function

but when I use the Google reference in my project like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine.

It is noteworthy I use telerik component in my project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you were typing your question, there was a **How to Format** box to the right. Worth a read, as is the various information linked to the **[?]** above the text area. There's also a preview area underneath where you can see the result prior to posting (and an "edit" link on the posted result if you see something after the fact). JaredPar has fixed most of it for you on this occasion. It's also worth noting that taking the time to use correct spelling and capitalization shows respect for the community. :-)

Comment: Sounds like your local jquery.js is not loaded, verify it using firebug.

Comment: Its happening because your browser isn't able to load the jQuery library. When you say "local", are you opening a file as in file://c/somefolder/page.htm? Or are you using IIS or Apache? Are you using Visual Studio's built in web server?

Comment: Seems like you've already figured out what the problem is.

Comment: I also want to point out that your local copy is v1.7.1 and you're loading v1.4.1 from Google. That isn't causing your current problem, but the difference may cause issues down the road. Pick a single version of jQuery and stick to it.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the problem is simply that the relative path for the import is incorrect.  Hence it's not loading jQuery and the call to `$(document).ready` is undefined.

You need to correct the path to the Scripts folder.

Answer (score 0):

most probably ur not loading jquery right
Take these steps :

- use developper tools in your browser (my favorite is firebug for firefox)
- go to the scripts tab and check if jquery.js is there
- if its there and its empty, check the url, maybe ur relative path is incorrect. to verify it you can put the url in your browser and fix it until the js file loads